# Missing from clause in a valid inner join request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this:

```
SELECT tbl1.* as tbl1 from table1
inner join table2 as tbl2
on tbl1.id = tbl2.table1_id
where tbl2.something = xxx;
```

why does it throw an exception

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tbl1"
LINE 3: on tbl1.id = tbl2.table1_id
           ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line, you have `as tbl1` and `from table1` in the wrong order.

it should be:

```
select  tbl1.*
from    table1 as tbl1
inner join table2 as tbl2
on      tbl1.id = tbl2.table1_id
where   tbl2.something = xxx;
```